# ¿Cuál es este uso de "meta" en Argentina? (Mafalda y Les Luthiers)

Tags: uso-de-palabras, argentina

Confieso que nunca he entendido esta tira de Mafalda:

[image]

Trascribo el texto para que aparezca en las búsquedas:

> **Guille:** ¡Zi Mafadda va a la ezcuela, yo también quiedo id!
>   **Madre:** Más adelante, Guille, todavía no podés.
>   **G:** ¡Quiedo id y voy a id! ¿Pod qué no puedo?
>   **M:** Porque sos muy chiquito todavía, no te dejarían entrar.
>   **G:** ¿Muy chiquito? ¡Dezde que nací eztoy **meta** y **meta** vivid! ¿Qué
>   pretenden ezoz?

Por otro lado, hay otro uso de *meta* que tampoco entiendo, esta vez de Les Luthiers. Los relaciono porque tanto Quino como Les Luthiers son argentinos, aunque podrían ser dos usos diferentes. En "El explicado" [se canta](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6xfbBAD_HE#t=04m48s):

> *A la vera del fogón*
>   *Hay que ver la paisanada*
>   ***Meta** canto y guitarreada, **meta** vino y:*
>   *Pasteles de masa que se fríen o se hornean*
>   *y que tienen un relleno de carne picada,*
>   *condimentos, aceitunas y morrón*

Aquí parece una preposición y, si se sustituye *meta* por *entre*, por ejemplo, la frase toma algún sentido. Sin embargo, esta sustitución no funciona con la frase de Quino.

Ninguno de los [significados de *meta* en el DLE](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=meta) parace ajustarse a estas frases. ¿Alguien podría explicar el significado de *meta* en estas oraciones?

> - *¡Desde que nací estoy **meta** y **meta** vivir!*
> - *Hay que ver la paisanada **meta** canto y guitarreada, **meta** vino y empanada.*

Comment: Según yo, es del verbo _meter_ (pte. subj. 3a pers. sing.: _meta él_) y es un modismo (coloquial) para enfatizar que algo se hace con insistencia/tesón. Guille se queja de que no lo dejen entrar al colegio a pesar del empeño con que ha estado viviendo toda su ("larga") vida; _Les Luthiers_ destacan la manera en que la _paisanada_ canta, guitarrea, toma vino y come empanadas. Un símil más universal puede ser el uso de _que_ con repetición del verbo, p. ej. _dale que dale_ (v. [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UkbUarn), definiciones 14 y 16).

Comment: Una búsqueda de ["meta que meta"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22meta+que+meta%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=-B-FV9DVEIKFxASTqCA#q=%22meta+que+meta%22&safe=active&tbs=lr:lang_1ca%7Clang_1de%7Clang_1en%7Clang_1es%7Clang_1eo%7Clang_1fr%7Clang_1it&lr=lang_ca%7Clang_de%7Clang_en%7Clang_es%7Clang_eo%7Clang_fr%7Clang_it) hace parecer que la expresión existe. Sería coherente con que ese fuera su origen.

Comment: @Rafael Tu búsqueda de "meta que meta" me ha inspirado para buscar el "meta y meta" de Guille y he llegado enseguida a un [hilo de wordreference en el que se pregunta prácticamente lo mismo](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/meta-y-meta-inf.2903736/) (con otros ejemplos de la expresión). Allí, ukimix da una definición muy buena:  "meta y meta + vb = no para de vb". Entre tus comentarios y la explicación de Vladimir Nu sale una buena respuesta. Y ya quedaría fetén con alguna referencia de alguna autoridad lingüistica sobre la expresión.

Comment: Pero parece que los académicos no han estudiado la cuestión. Bien podría añadirse al DLE como modismo de allá, ya que aparece en la obra de (grandes) humoristas como Quino y Les Luthiers y de escritores como Samanta Schweblin (y seguro que hay más).

Comment: Como fan de Mafalda que soy, me ha encantado la pregunta. Tras leer los comentarios y respuestas, creo que la mejor adaptación al español de España sería _¡Desde que nací estoy venga y venga a vivir!_

Answer (score 11):

"Meta" quiere decir hacer algo con insistencia. Es muy común no sólo en Argentina, sino también en Chile por ejemplo (de donde yo soy originario), quizás también en otros países latinoamericanos.

"Meta vino y empanada" querría decir entonces que la paisanada toma vino y come empanadas insistentemente, con mucho ahínco.

Lo mismo para las otras frases, creo que se entiende la idea, ¿no?

Comment: Entonces, la protesta de Guille se debe a que él piensa que para "esos", no es suficiente el esfuerzo que él ha puesto en vivir (en crecer), así pues "¿qué pretenden esos?". ¿No?

Comment: Sí, eso es. Es por el esfuerzo que él considera que ha puesto en vivir y que eso no ha sido suficiente para "ganarse" el derecho a ir a la escuela.

Comment: Excelente. La de Les Luthiers si la entiende un Colombiano :-) , pero hasta leer esta explicación no entendía lo que quería decir Guille por lo que debo aportar que si hay diferencias regionales en el uso de "meta".  +1 a la respuesta y la pregunta.

Comment: Se usa también con un dativo superfluo, p.ej. "estábamos _métale_ chupando" (que significa "estábamos bebiendo mucho") .Deriva de "meter" con el sentido de "poner o colocar" como en "meter prisa".

Answer (score 8):

Coincido con los comentarios de arriba.

"Estoy meta y meta vivir", significa "estoy viviendo sin parar" o "vivo y no paro de vivir". Guille, que quiere ir a la escuela y se siente listo, se pregunta por qué a las autoridades no les alcanza que él desde que nació no ha parado de vivir.

Desde el punto de vista expresivo "meta" es el imperativo a la voz formal *usted* (común en Argentina). Hay que imaginarse un auto estancado en el barro y que alguien desde afuera -un desconocido que te trata de usted- te indica que pises el ascelerador con un "meta pata" (ponga el pie en el acelerador). Un "meta y meta" es la insistencia de la misma indicación. "Meta y meta" pata: siga pisando el acelerador, o pise sin parar que el auto así sale...

Como bien indicaron también, en voz informal sería "dale", por "dale gas" o "da gas al auto". En repetición hay expresiones como "dale que dale". Guille podría haber dicho "Estoy [dale que dale] vivir", explicado "Estoy [en la situación en la cual no he parado de] vivir".

En el caso de los Les Luthiers, hace referencia a una fiesta que "sigue y sigue" porque no se para de cantar y no para de llegar el vino. Aquí hay que imaginarse al anfitrión que no deja que la fiesta se acabe, ordenando más rondas de vino y pidiendo que sigan las canciones.

Comment: Muy esclarecedora la respuesta, Andrea. Muchas gracias por ella y bienvenida a [spanish.se], donde espero que colabores con más respuestas :)

Answer (score 7):

Esto dice al respecto Corominas en su Diccionario Etimológico, en la entrada sobre `meter`:

> Se nota hoy en toda América el empleo interjectivo de `métele` ’corre’, ’pégale’, ’trabaja’, ’dale’ (*Ca.*, 44; `metéle que son pasteles`, Carrizo, *Canc. Pop. de Tucumán*, glos.; etc.); especialmente en la Arg[entina] es popular el empleo de `meta` combinado con un infinitivo con el valor de ’mucho’, ’dale, venga’ (`meta ir y venir`; vid. *BDHA* III, 262); [...]

Comment: También es común su uso combinado con un sustantivo ('meta carne y ensalada'), y también es común en Chile.

Comment: La referencia que faltaba. Sigo pensando que, reuniendo todas las aportaciones, queda una respuesta estupenda para la _wiki_, habida cuenta del interés que ha despertado y de lo útil que puede ser para los estudiantes de español que entren a consultar. ¿Alguno se anima (Vladimir, angus, Rafael)? Me gustaría que la respuesta aceptada reuniera toda la información recopilada (con reconocimientos incluidos, claro).

Comment: @cdlvcdlv Acabo de ver por pura casualidad tu comentario, no recibí ninguna notificación. No sé bien a qué se refiere eso de la wiki.

Comment: @VladimirNu Como ha habido respuestas y comentarios que han aportado partes importantes de la respuesta, para hacer la consulta más sencilla a quien esté interesado (hispanohablantes o estudiantes de español), he pensado que lo más sencillo sería hacer una respuesta recopilando toda la información (explicaciones sobre su origen, alternativas inteligibles fuera de Argentina, referencias académicas, ejemplos en literatura...) y hacerla comunitaria (marcando la casilla _community wiki_) mejor que dar una por buena. Luego he visto que una respuesta así impide ganar puntos de reputación, (cont.)

Comment: ... así que será mejor hacer una nueva respuesta de este tipo y dejar el resto tal cual.

Answer (score 1):

> Meta y ponga: (pop.) En forma continuada, sin perder el ritmo de marcha, trabajo o acción, reiteración de un acto, cópula.'

- "Estaba ahí **meta** jug**ando** play(meta+actividad) y me llamaron a comer"=>"Estaba jugando super concentrado harto rato PlayStation® sin prestar atención a otra cosa"(ensimismado/a)
- "Enojada porque estaba **meta** bail**ando**(meta+actividad) siguiendo los pasos del programa y llega mi papá a ver tele y me corta la toda la inspiración"(en su salsa, concentrada; metido o disfrutando, gozándola, **pasándolo chancho** p.ej: **meta** cumbia)

> Pasarlo chancho: Pasarla chancho es sinónimo de pasar un rato extremadamente agradable. Esta frase se origina al observar que el coito del cerdo pude durar hasta 30 minutos.

Es parecida a otras formas como 'malo que te [acción]'

- **Malo** que te arreglai[arreglas]/preocupai[preocupas]/discutí[discutes]/hablai[hablas] oh'

Para decir en este caso con **malo** que+te/se/me=>(es como) mucho, demasiado, desproporcionado, inapropiado, harto de, etc, en un **registro coloquial** que sorprende lo reiterada y desproporcionada que es la acción en relación a una determinada situación como diciendo p.ej:

- **Malo** **que** **te** preocup**ai**[preocup**as**] de eso => "Dale que dale con la misma cosa **si** no es para tanto".
- **Malo** **que** **se** preocup**an** si... => "No es necesario que (UDs.) se preocup**en** tanto **porque**...".
- **Malo** **que** **me** preocup**o** **si**... => No debería preocupar**me** tanto **porque**...
- **Malo** **que** discute**n** oh => "**Para** que discuten (UDs.) tanto **si**..." (no van a llegar a ningún acuerdo, no se va a sacar nada, no van a sacar nada en limpio)
- **Meta** habl**ando** de lo mismo, ya me aburrió => "Ya él/ella me aburrió, habla **siempre** la misma cosa"(monotonía, rutina)
- **Malo que se** arregla**n** si.. => "No se arregl**en** tanto (UDs.) **si** no vamos a un evento/**si** vamos a la esquina nomás".

Answer (score 1):

Gente!

Me crucé con esto por casualidad, y vengo a "darles una mano" como decimos en Argentina.

En ambos ejemplos de "meta" que pusieron, no se trata de Español, Castellano, ni Argentino.

Es un término del "Lunfardo", una lengua que se originó y se hablaba exclusivamente en ambas orillas del Río de la plata: Buenos Aires (sobre todo su periferia) y Montevideo (Uruguay).

Se originó alrededor de 1880, primero como jerga carcelaria (la comunicación de los presos, para que la policía no entienda), se esparció por los barrios más pobres, "conventiyos", "arrabales", y su difusión y expansión, que incluía a Rosario(la 2da en poblacion luego de Buenos Aires, y puerto granero  Argentino) y otras ciudades de Santa Fé, coincidió con una gran ola inmigratoria de Europa de la época.
Ya para la decada 20-30 del siglo XX, era una lengua que contenía terminos y mezclas de Italiano , Español, Arabe, Portugués, y lenguas africanas, y se hablaba en la población urbana y suburbana mezclado al castellano.
Todo esto, gracias a la difusión del Lunfardo en el tango,(en esa época, las letras de tango eran casi todas con lunfardo) y las victrolas, por supuesto.

"Meta" (esto o aquello), significa repetir una acción, insistir, hacer algo con cierta fijación, o con mucho placer. ("meta vino y empanadas")
El término más cercano sería, "dale que dale" o "dale que te dale" en Español

Espero les haya gustado la explicación, y se hayan quedado con ganas de más lunfardo.

Answer (score 0):

Son correctos los comentarios de arriba: lleva un sentido de insistencia. Pero además en Salta, de donde yo soy, " meta", así aislado, significa la aceptación de una propuesta. Por ejemplo, "¿Vas a jugar conmigo? , Rta: "Meta". ( significa que sí, o "de acuerdo")

Answer (score 0):

Uso de "Meta", del verbo meter, meter, poner adentro, como si la circunstancia fuera una bolsa y dentro le metieran unidades de intención, meterle ganas.

- "Meta empanadas", es meterle muchas empanadas a, en este caso el gaucho.

Answer (score 0):

Así es, pero también en distintas regiones de Argentina, se usa la palabra "meta". Cuando alguien dice de quedar y encontramos en tal o cual lugar, respondemos, con un simple; "**meta**".

Igualmente cuando decimos, ¿vienes?, o argentinizando ¿venís?, te responden "**meta**"... Y así con cada cuestión de este estilo.

Supongo que equivale a lo que usualmente los españoles, responden con la expresión "**vale**".